# Error loading image to set background

Tags: java, image

I am trying to load an image and set to background, but i get the error at selectionPanel method "Could not load background image".

It seems that something is going wrong with the image processing but i cant find out what.

```
public class selectionPanel extends JPanel
{
  //Variable with the name of our pic
  private static final String path = "selbkgrnd.jpg";
  private ImageIcon imageIcon;
  private Dimension windowSize;
  private int imageHeight;
  private int imageWidth;

  protected selectionPanel()
  {

    this.imageIcon = new ImageIcon("selbkgrnd.jpg"); //Save image to imageIcon
    Image image = this.imageIcon.getImage();
    this.imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
    this.imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
    if ((this.imageWidth == -1) || (this.imageHeight == -1)) //Check if background image is succesfully loaded
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.getDesktopPaneForComponent(this), "Could not load background image", "Fatal error!", 0);

      System.exit(-1);
    }
    this.windowSize = new Dimension(this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
  }

  protected void startScreen()
  {
    setOpaque(false);
    setSize(this.windowSize);
  }

  protected int getImageHeight()
  {
    return imageHeight;
  }

  protected int getImageWidth()
  {
    return imageWidth;
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawImage(this.imageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    super.paintComponent(g);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is due to your looking in the wrong location for your Image File. Try using the complete path to the image, either that or a path relative to the user's directory which can be found with:

```
System.out.println("user directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

**Edit**
You state:

> Thank you it worked with the full path, but isnt it supposed to work with just the image name if it is inside the source code folder ?

No. Again, Java will look for the file relative to the user directory.

Note however that if the image is in the class file directory or in a directory relative to this and you make a jar file out of this and need to access the images, then you can't use files. You will need to get the images as a *resource* and the relative path will be *different* since it won't be related to the user.dir but rather will be relative to the location of the class files.

Comment: The image is inside the source code folder. I will try what you said.

Comment: Thank you it worked with the full path, but isnt it supposed to work with just the image name if it is inside the source code folder ?